# Calculus, local linearization

Tags: calculus, derivatives

(a)Given that$$ f(7)=13$$ and$$ f′(7)=−0.38$$, estimate f(7.1).

My answer was$$ f(6.1)= 13+ -0.38(x-7)$$ = 13.342.

(b)Suppose also $$ f′′(x)<0 $$for all $x$. Does this make your answer to part (a) an under- or overestimate?

My assumption is: $$ f′′(x)<0 $$ this means that it is concave down, so $f'(x)$ is decreasing and $f(x)$ is negative. Therefore, it is underestimate. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

$$f(7.1)\approx f(7)+0.1\times f'(7)+\frac{0.1^2}{2}f''(7)$$
So if $f''(7)<0$, you previous answer was over-estimated (Bad luck, you had a fifty-fifty chance of being right ;) )

Comment: Let me ask you a question first : from where do you bring $f(x)= 13+ -0.38(x-7)$ ?

Comment: let me answer your question : f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)

Comment: So with the same way of thinking : $f'(x)=f'(a) + f''(a)(x-a)$. Then try to integrate from $a$ to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since $f(x)$ is always concave down, think of a representative function that is also concave down, like a parabola such as $-x^2$. Sketch a graph, and pick any point (call it $P$). Now draw a tangent line at $P$. Making a linear approximation is tantamount to starting from $P$, travelling along this tangent line, then estimating the actual height of the parabola by using the approximate height via the tangent line. So: is your tangent line above or below the parabola?

Comment: If we use a parabola such as -x^2 the tangent line will always be over estimate. But for this QUESTION, DO I NEED TO LOOK at the equation? or Just the the f''(x) < 0 ?

Comment: So you are saying that it is overestimate ?

Comment: @user157908 I think he is right.

Comment: Provided that $f(x)$ is concave down on an open interval containing the approximation (in this case, at $x = 7.1$), it is guaranteed to be an overestimate. Indeed, some people use this as a definition of concave down (for example, see this: http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Calculus/Sign2ndDer/Sign2DerPOI.htm).